# SwiftUI view not updating when a child object is deleted from SwiftData

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

```
@Model
class Category: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    
    @Relationship var questions = [Question]()

}   

@Model
class Question: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var text: String

    @Relationship var category: Category?

    init(id: Int, text: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
    }
    
}

struct EditCategoryView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Bindable var category: Category //Bindable because I can also edit the category title on this screen

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
                        ForEach(category.questions) { question in
                            HStack {
                                Text(question.text)
                                    .baseTextStyle()
                                
                                Spacer()

                                Button(action: {
                                    delete(question: question)
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Delete")
                                })
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                        }
                    }
    }

    func delete(question: Question) {
        modelContext.delete(question)
        try! modelContext.save()
    }
}
```

Nothing happens visually when the Delete button is pressed. But if I leave the screen and come back, the deleted question will be gone. So the deletion is happening but `category` is not being observed for some reason.

How can I get the view to respond to the deletion of a Question object, which is a child of Category?

Comment: you need a `@Query` for `Question`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now the change doesn't reflect automatically.

Though your shared code is not compilable, but you need to also manually remove from the array to show the changes immediately in the view.

```swift
    func delete(question: Question) {
        guard let index = category.questions.firstIndex(of: question) else {
            return
        }
        category.questions.remove(at: index)
        modelContext.delete(question)
        try! modelContext.save()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `@Bindable` for your `Category` object so this what SwiftUI is observing in your view.

But what happens to the Question object in memory when you delete it is that is marked as deleted but not removed so it remains in the `questions` array.

To handle this (at least for now because it looks like a bug) is to also remove it from the array in the delete function and then this will trigger a view update since we now have updated `category` in a way that SwiftUI notices.

```
func delete(question: Question) {
    if let index = category.questions.firstIndex(of: question) {
        category.questions.remove(at: index)
    }
    modelContext.delete(question)
    try! modelContext.save()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you able find a solution other than the accepted one, which suggests to manually delete from the modelcontext?

I have a similar setup, where I would want to `update` the category or one of the questions. So an `insert` or `delete` is not sufficient, but there is no method to update an object on the modelContext, only `insert` and `delete`.

We must be missing something obvious, but can't put my finger on it...